# Cannot navigate easily from test runner output to the relevant file in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, npm, webstorm

When running npm test from within WebStorm I get nice output shown like this:

```
Error: invalid input syntax for integer: "***"
at Massive.DB.query (paymentweb/app/node_modules/massive/lib/runner.js:22:11)
at Table.insert (paymentweb/app/node_modules/massive/lib/table.js:45:11)
at Table.tryCatcher (paymentweb/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
at Table.ret [as insertAsync] (eval at makeNodePromisifiedEval (paymentweb/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promisify.js:184:12), <anonymous>:13:39)
at db.(anonymous function).findOneAsync.then.existing (paymentweb/app/src/services/paymentdb/index.js:59:22)
at tryCatcher (paymentweb/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
```

My problem is I cannot easily navigate from the errors to the files in my project. Normally the file names in stacktraces and similar are highlighted and I can open the file simply by clicking the link.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried Cmd+Clicking the filenames? Might be Ctrl+Click on windows. At least in terminals, this is the way to visit URIs or paths.

Comment: Yes, I tried various combinations but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Webstorm does not support this kind of linking.

Your best alternative is probably the *"Navigate to File"* shortcut which is `Ctrl+Shift+N`.

This will popup a modal dialog for quick search / navigation to a file.

Eg, `Ctrl+Shift+N`, `<enter file search term>`, `Enter` will let you quickly jump to a file.

Comment: Yes, I use this frequently. But first of all this is not as efficient as the direct link. And furthermore, for many NodeJS applications files are often named index.js, which makes it even more tedious.

Comment: This bounty was raised to give me a fix. However, to be fair I will give the bounty anyway as this was the only answer given.